# Creating a foreign key reference to a User in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am fairly new to ASP.NET MVC and working on a small project in which I have a table called `Tests` in which I would like to add a foreign key reference to the `UserID` in the `aspnet_Users` table.

Which is the best way to do this? Is there any recommended way of doing it?

Should I have a Guid property in my Tests model:

```
public virtual Guid UserID { get; set; }
```

or it's better to have a navigation property:

```
public virtual ???? User { get; set; }
```

Which is the best way to do this and any hints on how I could implement this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `UserID` in `sapnet_Users` is indeed a `Guid` (a `uniqueidentifier` in the SQL Server table), then yes - if you want to reference a specific user, you need to have a `Guid` value at hand.

If you want to have a navigation property that references the `User` type directly - you'd need to make sure you have the `User` as a type in your app, and you might need to specify the FK constraint name (in whatever data model you have).

I would think, both approaches work. If you only need to set the `Guid` and nothing else - approach #1 is fine and sufficient.

If you will need to read out (and possibly set) other properties of the `User` class - then I think approach #2 would be the better choice, even though it's slightly more involved / more effort on your part.